# Angular ng-repeat table: dynamic columns from object

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a table that would look like this:

```
20       23        25       26
734.53   279.20    936.95   584.50
```

based on this Object:

```
{
    "20": 734.5339864003384,
    "23": 279.20378246766563,
    "25": 936.9526667106079,
    "26": 584.5060233468447,
    "27": 279.20378246766563,
    "28": 2055.970661511549,
    "29": 1405.0981690224412,
    "30": 549.4917661928141,
    "31": 2329.1464674575695,
    "32": 147.8822594632703,
    "33": 698.0104349592335
}
```

Obviously the title of the column needs to be dynamic according to the keys of the JSON and the value should correspond.

I have the following code but i am not sure at all if I am on the right track:

***JS***

```
 $scope.modal = {};
    $scope.modal.keys = [];
    $scope.modal.data = [];
    for (var key in assets.total) {
      if (assets.total.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $scope.modal.keys.push(key);
        $scope.modal.data.push(assets.total[key]);
      }
    }
```

***HTML***

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="th in modal.key">{{th}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in modal.data">
      <td ng-repeat="th in modal.key">{{x[th]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It is just not working I get a strange result with only one column.

Comment: Looks like keys is modal.keys misspelled. Should it be modal.keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution

use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in Array"` for get key value in object.

I have create a demo on [**Working Demo on Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-repeat-table-dynamic-columns-from-object?file=home%2Fhome.html)

and remove `for (var key in assets.total)` loop.

html code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"> {{key}} </th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"> {{ value| number: 2 }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> Js file code

```
$scope.data = {
      "20": 734.5339864003384,
      "23": 279.20378246766563,
      "25": 936.9526667106079,
      "26": 584.5060233468447,
      "27": 279.20378246766563,
      "28": 2055.970661511549,
      "29": 1405.0981690224412,
      "30": 549.4917661928141,
      "31": 2329.1464674575695,
      "32": 147.8822594632703,
      "33": 698.0104349592335
}
```